# Port 5432 listening but unreachable after installing Postgres

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, tcp

I have an Ubuntu VM, hosted with Microsoft Azure. It was completely blank, and then I installed Postgres using `sudo apt-get install postgresql`.

The version I installed is `Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`.

I configured Postgres in order to accept remote connections, by following [this tutorial](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html):

- I edited my `postgresql.conf` file by setting `listen_addresses = '*'`.
- I edited my `pg_hba.conf` file by adding the two following lines:

  `host    all     all     0.0.0.0/0     md5`

  `host    all     all     ::/0          md5`

And I restarted Postgres, and even the whole server for good measure.

When I execute `netstat -tln`, I obtain the following result:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

My `iptables` are totally empty, I did not do anything with it after creating the VM.

From another client, I tried to execute `sudo -u postgres psql -h [host] -U postgres`, and the request times out.

When I execute `telnet [host] 5432` from another client, nothing happens until it times out. However, executing `telnet [host] 22` works fine, and executing `telnet [host] 80` gets me a connexion refused, which I assume means that my host is at least listening on these ports.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Could be missing: 1. `[host]` not being the public IP address actually assigned or routed to your VM. The fact that `telnet [host] 22` does answer does not prove that the destination is your VM (why not try to log in with ssh, btw?). 2. A firewall between the VM and your client, including on your client. Timeout on certain ports and not others is almost invariably  the work of a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try switching as postgres user and enter `psql` on the machine where postgres is installed. This will make sure the installation is correct or wrong.

```
su - postgres
psql
```

Check the firewall in Azure console, probably you will have to enable port 5432.

More information about how to open ports on an Azure VM can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I switched as postgres user and everything is fine with the install (I created a database as well). My Azure account has no firewall set, so I don't think this is an issue either.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal

Comment: Hello, and sorry for the delay. You were right, the problem was actually Azure Firewall not allowing port 5432 by default. I did not know where to look and your link pointed me in the right direction. You should add it to the answer. :)
Thanks for your help!